# Different answers to the same queries cUrl (Steam Market)

Tags: php, curl, steam, steam-web-api

When in the browser you follow the link:

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US%C2%A4cy=5&appid=570&market_hash_name=Gem%20of%20Taegeuk

Gives out { "success": false }, In headings 500 a mistake. But when I do the same inquiry through cUrl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=5&appid=570&market_hash_name=Gem%20of%20Taegeuk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);   
$curl = curl_exec($ch);
```

In response, instead of json I get this:

> ‹ЄV*.MNN-.VІJKМ)N­яятКC4

Tell me how to fix this and what might be the cause of the error (500)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server return gzipped response (header `Content-Encoding: gzip`). So, you need auto encoding:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');`

P.S. Browser unlike the `curl` unpacks the response automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) There's an additional `%C2%A4cy%` and missing `curren` after `country=US` in the example link. The URL in CURL looks ok.

2) Your CURL commands do not follow redirects, the URL should be with `https://` (browser does that automatically). You can follow redirects with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`